# How do you close a window from another class in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have been having an issue trying to close a Login window from another Controller class. The Login window is opened in Main.java but the fxml file is controlled by LoginController.java. I have tried to extend the Main.java class to close the stage, but this isn't working. I have tried to make pass through methods as well but did not have much luck. Here is my code:

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Parent root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
public class LoginController extends Main implements Initializable{
    public LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();


    @FXML
    private Label isConnected;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private Button cancelButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (loginModel.isDbConnected()) {
            isConnected.setText("Connected");
        } else {
            isConnected.setText("Not Connected");
        }
    }

    public void Login (ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if (loginModel.isLogin(txtUsername.getText(), txtPassword.getText())) {
                isConnected.setText("Username and password are correct");
                ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml").openStream());
                //UserController userController = (UserController)loader.getController();
                //userController.GetUser(txtUsername.getText());
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();


            } else {
                isConnected.setText("Username and password are not correct");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            isConnected.setText("Username and password are not correct");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancelLogin() {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

FXML line of code:

```
<Button layoutX="110.0" layoutY="125.0" minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelLogin" text="Cancel" />
```

I have also tried creating a Main object in the LoginController and using main.window.close(); but that does not seem to work either (this was before extending Main). Any help would be greatly appreaciated, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing `Main` won't make any difference, and neither will creating a `window` field in an object that is not the controller object your method is being called on. You just need to get a reference to the window.

You can do, for example,

```
public void cancelLogin() {
    cancelButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

as long as you have mapped the button correctly (it looks like you have omitted the `fx:id` in the FXML):

```
<Button fx:id="cancelButton" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="125.0" minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelLogin" text="Cancel" />
```

Of course, if your actual aim is to exit the application entirely, you could do that with

```
public void cancelLogin() {
    Platform.exit();
}
```

Comment: it is still not working, giving me a runtime exception and invocationTargetException. Plus I would like to close the program completely. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: "It gives me an exception" is pretty useless, unless you actually say what the cause of the exception is. It looks like you didn't include an `fx:id` in your FXML though. See update.

Comment: Awesome, that solved it, thanks a million! I tried to upvote, but don't have 15 points yet. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answers the question. You do not need any reputation for that.